# How to change the color of a NavigationView separator/divider (SwiftUI & MacOS)?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm trying to change the colour of the NavigationView separator from black to a lighter colour, as pictured below:

[image: NavigationView divider/separator]

I have changed the background colour of the NavigationView as well as the colour of the app's window. It is also in a ZStack with a light colour.

Any help in resolving this would be helpful. This is my code:

```
NavigationView {
             VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                 //temporary save button
                 Button(action:{ self.save()}, label: {Text("Temp Save button").foregroundColor(Color.blue)})
                 
                 //Title of sidebar
                 Text("Docs").foregroundColor(Color.init(red: 0.69, green: 0.64, blue: 0.54, opacity: 1.00)).bold().padding(.leading)
                 
                 //links to the documents
                ScrollView {
                    links
                    }.frame(minWidth: 200, maxWidth: 200, alignment: .leading)
             }
                }.navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle())
             .background(Color.init(red: 1.00, green: 0.99, blue: 0.98, opacity: 1.00))
```

Let me know if providing any more information would be of help.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same question and did not find an answer…

Comment: @kezhenxu94 Did u find an answer?